# AudioUnits causing universal skipping after returning from Springboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audiounit

I have a problem in my applications where I am using AudioUnits.  All of the applications Audio (including audio not played through AudioUnits) will start skipping after exiting to Springboard and returning to the applications.

I broke out the problem into a new separate test app.  Here are the steps to repeat it:

- Start an Audio file playing using an
  AVAudioPlayer.
- Create, Delete, then again Create an
  AudioUnit
- Exit to Springboard
- Return to the app
- The Audio from the AvAudioPlayer will start skipping

Here is some of the code I used:

```
- (IBAction)restartAudioUnit {

    MySoundStream* audioUnitClass;
    audioUnitClass = Load();
    [audioUnitClass release];
    audioUnitClass = Load();

}
```

Forgive the long code dump but AudioUnits are complex and I am fairly sure I am just setting them up or taking them down incorrectly.

The MySoundStream class:

```
OSStatus UnitRenderCB(void* pRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags* flags, const AudioTimeStamp* timeStamp, UInt32 busNum, UInt32 numFrames, AudioBufferList*  pData){

    OSStatus tErr = noErr;

    //Do Nothing

    return tErr;
}

@implementation MySoundStream

-(void) dealloc {

    [self Unload];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) Unload {

    OSStatus tErr = noErr; 
    tErr = AudioUnitUninitialize(OutUnit);
}

@end

MySoundStream* Load()
{
    OSStatus tErr = noErr;
    AudioComponentInstance tRIO;
    AudioComponentDescription tRIOCD;
    AURenderCallbackStruct tRIOCB;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription tAUF;

    tRIOCD.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    tRIOCD.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    tRIOCD.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    tRIOCD.componentFlags = 0;
    tRIOCD.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AudioComponent tRIOC = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &tRIOCD);
    tErr = AudioComponentInstanceNew(tRIOC, &tRIO);
    if (tErr != noErr) return NULL;

    int tOutEnable = 1;

    tErr = AudioUnitSetProperty(tRIO, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &tOutEnable, sizeof(tOutEnable));
    if (tErr != noErr) return NULL; 

    tAUF.mSampleRate = 44100.00;
    tAUF.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    tAUF.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    tAUF.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    tAUF.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    tAUF.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    tAUF.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    tAUF.mBytesPerFrame = 4;

    tErr = AudioUnitSetProperty(tRIO, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &tAUF, sizeof(tAUF));
    if (tErr != noErr) return false;

    MySoundStream* pRet = [MySoundStream alloc];

    tRIOCB.inputProc = UnitRenderCB;
    tRIOCB.inputProcRefCon = pRet;
    tErr = AudioUnitSetProperty(tRIO, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &tRIOCB, sizeof(tRIOCB));
    if (tErr != noErr){ delete pRet; return NULL; }

    tErr = AudioUnitInitialize(tRIO);
    if (tErr != noErr){ delete pRet; return NULL; }

    pRet->OutUnit = tRIO;

    return pRet;
}
```

If anyone can see anything I am doing wrong with this AudioUnit, that woudl be very helpful.

Edit:
Upload the complete source. [Here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/cb999ea/n/TestAudioUnitApp.zip)

1. Press Play Sound (may need headphones)
2. Press RestartAudioUnit
3. Return to Springboard
4. Re-enter TestAudioUnit app

Audio will skip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to using an AUGraph to setups my Audio Unit path and I had better luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `AudioUnitInitialize()` when the app is re-initialized, which is not good. You need to call `AudioUnitInitialize()` only once when your app starts, and you should not have to build the entire AU graph every time your app enters the foreground.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I call AudioUnitInitialize, then Uninit, then Init again while the app is running.  As if I am shutting down the Unit, reconfiguring it, and starting it again.  Is that not allowed?  Then after its reconfigured I exit to Spring and return, no calls to AudioUnit anything.

Comment: I might have found my bug while looking into this.  There is an AudioSessionInitialize that I wasn't calling, which the docs say should be called once then never again, was this what you were referring to?

Comment: Added source in update, AudioSessionInitialize is being called.

Comment: @TurqMage Yes, you should only call AudioSessionInitialize *once* in your program's initialization. Calling it multiple times (ie, when your application enters the foreground or restarts the audio subsystem) is not good. Make a single call to it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your delegate and nowhere else.